# Chart.js in flex element overflows instead of shrinking

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, chart.js

I have tried setting the min-width to 0 on the wrapper div for chart.js, but the chart will grow and then not shrink back down if you drag the window around.

I can't figure it out! The only thing I can do is set width to 99% but then the chart is no longer aligned with my other divs. I've been working on this for days, please help!

**Q: How can I get chart.js to be 100% width, and grow/shrink to it's bounding size.**

**to reproduce, go to the example and if you close the menu, the chart grows, and if you open it, the chart does not shrink back down. it maintains it's size and overflows to the right.**

**note**: my actual project has two separate components for the chart and side bar. So a calc solution doesn't work in this case, I don't want to tightly couple any components to maintain good practice.

[Here is my StackBlitz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-overflow-ex)

here are pictures to show the reproduction:

1. chart is the right size, menu open
   [image]
2. chart grows when you close the menu (the size is still correct)
   [image]
3. open the menu, and the chart overflows right
   [image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Not able to figure out what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking forward to having two divs side by side with flexible width on the page? or you want a full with chat no matter what divs are present on the page?

Comment: I updated the example. basically, if you close the menu, the chart grows, and if you open it, the chart does not shrink back down. it maintains it's size and overflows to the right.

Comment: Now that's much more clear. Check out my answer.

Comment: I can't get stackblitz to run (JS errors due to tracking protection in Firefox) so I can't verify this (hence comment instead of answer), but I had that exact issue in my flex layout and solved it by ensuring `overflow: hidden` was set on the parent (and ancestor) flex elements. A cursory look at your CSS shows this is only done on `.page-wrapper`.

Comment: @timclutton so add it to my canvas wrapper? anything else?

Comment: @timclutton dude! using that and min-width: 0; made it work!!! post your answer man, I'll throw you some points

Answer (score 35, accepted):

(Copied from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502837/chart-js-in-flex-element-overflows-instead-of-shrinking?noredirect=1#comment91972565_52502837).)

I can't get StackBlitz to run (JS errors due to tracking protection in Firefox) so I can't verify this, but I had that exact issue in my flex layout and solved it by ensuring `overflow: hidden` was set on the parent (and ancestor) flex elements. A cursory look at your CSS shows this is only done on `.page-wrapper`.

Comment: how in the world did you manage to get to this solution? you saved my day! :)

Comment: this no longer works

Comment: for me it still works, tysm

Comment: Can anyone speak to why this works?

Comment: It is not obvious to me at all why this works, but yet it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Wrapping the canvas in a div with width 100% and and setting the canvas to max-width 100% works for me:

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
    <canvas id="chart" style="max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Update: This solution stopped working with chart.js 3

I had similar problems with a markup like this:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
  <h2>...</h2>
  <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; flex: 1">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <span>...</span>
  <span>...</span>
</div>
```

My outermost div was in a css-grid, maybe that also played a role.

Anyhow, I diagnosed the problem to be this: Even though I applied `{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }` to the options of chart.js, the chart had a fixed size, which caused the chart-container not to shrink (even when `overflow: hidden` was applied, I don't fully understand why). This caused the div element chartjs inserts to detect size changes to never change its height.

So the solution was to simply **override the height on the canvas to 100%:** `canvas {height: 100%!important}`.

This allows the canvas container to shrink, causing the size-detection div to shrink, causing a re-render of the canvas, which prevents aspect-ratio issues.

Comment: This approach helped with chart not shrinking horizontally, only expanding when using Prime React ChartJS wrapper. With width: 100% !important applied to canvas it shrinks as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here your canvas is having width inside absolute parents so its recommended to change the values dynamically using JavaScript (angular in your case). But since you are looking for CSS based solution here is what you can add in your app.components.css file:

```
.sidebar-wrapper.shrink + div.main-wrapper canvas {
  width: calc(100vw - 40px) !important;
}
.sidebar-wrapper:not(.shrink) + div.main-wrapper canvas {
  width: calc(100vw - 230px) !important;
}
```

Here is the working example : https://chartjs-overflow-ex-vlsqmn.stackblitz.io/

Comment: ah shoot. is there any way this can be compatible with older versions of IE? vw isn't supported in several older browsers, and I could be wrong but several older browsers also don't support calculations in css.

Comment: yeah, % instead of wv would work just fine, its just you have to tweak the values a bit.

Comment: @FussinHussin please select the answer if it works for you and let me know if you have any query towards the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm gonna try it, I have a problem because those components are in two separate files.

Comment: any chance you know a flex-box solution?

Comment: while this solution works in the example situation, my actual project has multiple components. the side bar and the chart are separate, and to keep good practice I don't want to create a tight coupling between two components. do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Like I ment and tried to explain in the answer css is not the best solution, rather the best solution is to use chart.js API to change the width of the canvas as per any change in .main-wrapper or browser resize.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the canvas in a div with max-width 70% works for me:

```
<div class="division-chart-wrap">
    <canvas id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
<style>
      .division-chart-wrap {
        flex: 1 1 18rem;
        min-height: 12rem;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 70%;
      }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me, but the following finally did:

- Keep your original container div with `width: 100%` - overflow or min-width doesn't matter.  Depending on your implementation you might need to define a height either in CSS or in JS.
- Inside of that container, create another div and give it the following style:

```
.innerContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

So now your HTML would look something like (using React syntax):

```
<div className="originalContainer">
  <div className="innerContainer">
    <canvas width={'100%'} height={<whatever>} />
  </div>
</div>
```